# Can't modify frozen String error using gsub and hash

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to create a ruby rspec with capybara and I'm getting this error when attempting to remove part of a string from a hash: can't modify frozen String

```
scenario "check doc" do
docs = {
  'A doc' => 'a.txt',
  'B doc' => 'b.txt',
  'C doc' => 'c.txt'
}
random_doc = docs.keys.sample
page.should have_css('.class', :text => 'Document ' + random_doc.gsub!(' doc') + ' was selected')
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key name is frozen so you can't modify it in place - just use gsub rather than gsub! so that it returns a modified copy of the string rather than trying to do inplace modification

Comment: After doing just gsub, I'm getting a new error: no implicit conversion of Enumerator into String

Comment: @DonaldC. because gsub takes two parameters if you want it to return a string -  I'm guessing you want  `random_doc.gsub(' doc','')`

Comment: Just realized this after posting. Thanks for the help, much appreciated!

Comment: @DonaldC. You're welcome, if the answer helped you, don't forget to accept the answer (the checkmark) so that the question gets marked as answered